# Count case when *

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, psql

I am getting an error in my count case statement and I was hoping I could get some help.

My line of code is

```
count(case when product = 'classic' then * end)
```

and the error message that I am getting is

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "*"
>   LINE 4: ...t(case when initial_product_line = 'classic' then * end) as ...

can I not do a count *?
                                                             ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` has special meaning in `SQL`, you need either `1` or `columnname` instead :

```
count(case when product = 'classic' then col end)
```

You can also simplify it as :

```
sum(case when product = 'classic' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally use `sum()`:

```
sum(case when product = 'classic' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Amazon Redshift doesn't support the latest Postgres functionality, but Postgres implements the filter clause, which is nice:

```
count(*) filter (where product = 'classic')
```

I just bring this up because it is standard syntax and related to your version of the query (and supported by a related database).